# Android - how to switch activity on image click

Tags: java, android, mobile

Here I've got this code

```
switchact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) 
      {
        Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
        startActivity(act2);
      }
    });
```

And i've got image on my activity/layout1.
How do I make that when I click on the image it switched to activity 2?

Comment: You can use view.getContext() to getApplicationContext() ot ActivityName.this

Comment: Intent act2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Activity2.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a listener on the image over the onClick event, try something like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(act2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent act2 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

startActivity(act2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent act2 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

      startActivity(act2);
    }
});
```